# How can I write sensor data to an SD card without getting gaps in data?

Tags: microcontroller, sensor

I'm currently working on a project where I have a sensor I need to sample at about 20 KHz, with each sample being 6 bytes (for now). Roughly, it's 1 Mbps. I have both a Feather M0 Adalogger and a Feather M4 Express I can work with, but it would be much better if I can get this to work on the M0.

Currently, on the M0 (as far as I can tell), any time the internal buffer fills up before writing to the SD card, the board will start dropping sensor data until the buffer data is written to the SD card. In the end, this leaves me with something like 8-12% data drop rate which is obviously not good.

What can I do to get around this? Is it a limitation of the board itself?

I am relatively new to embedded programming, so please let me know if there's any misconceptions you've spotted or if there's any other information you may need to help me further!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have no access to the board firmware, then it sounds like a limitation of the board due to buffer size or buffer handling, combined with the SD card worst-case write latency.

You may be able to get better performance with a different SD card. Probably with a faster throughput one, though that's not necessarily true.

Comment: It does look like some sort of board limitation so I have a gimmicky solution in mind lol. Thank you for the reply and sry for the lag

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to multitask reading the sensor and writing to the card.

When you have a data producer and a data consumer running concurrently the usual way is to connect them through a [FIFO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFO_(computing_and_electronics)). A simple implementation is a [ring buffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer) in RAM. Another way is to use a double buffer: one buffer is being filled while the other is being written, and when the first buffer is full they are swapped.

On a M0 you're probably not using any OS. The sensor read be done in two ways:

If it's something that needs CPU intervention like sending a SPI command and reading the reply, then you need a timer interrupt set to trigger every 50µs (20kHz)  that launches the process. Due to variable interrupt latency (it may have to wait for a higher priority interrupt to finish before running) this can introduce high sampling jitter.

If it's the micro's internal ADC, then you should be using its features: on most M0 chips you get quite a lot of stuff, for example you can configure a timer to trigger every 50µs and set the ADC to start conversion from this signal. This has the lowest sampling jitter as the timer triggers the ADC directly. Now the ADC will work automatically. It generates an "end of conversion" signal so you configure one of the channels on the DMA peripheral to trigger on this, read the ADC data register and write it to a buffer in RAM. Once configured it will write each sample into the buffer automatically while incrementing the address, and when it reaches the end it'll wrap around to the beginning. This occurs without CPU intervention. Then you set the DMA controller to raise an interrupt when the buffer is half full and when it  wraps around. In both cases, one half of the buffer contains data that is ready to be written to SD. So when this interrupt code is called, it can either write to SD, or signal the main thread to do so. Another option is to have the main thread loop and watch the DMA controller registers to check how much was written to RAM, then flush it to SD.

Basically "all you have to do" is to check out the reference manual for your micro and figure out how to program it to do this. Most manufacturers will give you some kind of hardware abstraction library to avoid setting bits in registers directly, and you may even find some tutorials.

The Arduino "OS" will probably not be able to do this, but it allows you to go bare metal and tweak the registers directly or use the manufacturer's libraries. But since this board is basically an Arduino Zero, someone has probably [done it already](https://forum.arduino.cc/t/using-adc-with-dma/498085) and put it on github.

Comment: Thank you, I'll be looking into all this :) Sorry for the lag.